# Trading Platform APIs which support editing holdings

Tags: programming, testing

I am developing a tool to assist human traders using a trading platform. For testing, I was wondering if anyone was aware of any trading platforms which support editing the holdings of a paper account.

For example, when logged into the paper account, I can edit the holdings via the API to show the account is holding a certain equity at a given cost basis.

I took a look at IB, but I don't see a way to edit the account holdings via an API (if it's a paper account).